# While loop won't terminate in java even though numerical case is matched in boolean value

Tags: java

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class LogicTableGenerator

{

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        double numletters;
        System.out.println("how many letters exist in your logic table?");
        numletters=TextIO.getInt(); double totalpremises;
        totalpremises=Math.pow(2.0,numletters);
        System.out.println("what letters are you using?");
        char letter; letter = 'A'; char letter1, letter2, letter3, letter4,letter5,letter6,letter7,letter8,letter9;
        int numstop; numstop =0;
        System.out.println(numstop);
        boolean bag;
        bag=(1!=1);
        System.out.println(bag);

        while (!(numstop == 1))
        {
            letter1=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("Do you awant to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            System.out.println(numstop);
            letter2=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println(numstop);
            System.out.println("Do you want to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            letter3=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("Do you want to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            letter4=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("Do you want to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            letter5=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("Do you want to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            letter6=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("Do you want to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            letter7=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("Do you want to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            letter8=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("Do you want to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            letter9=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("You have reached the end of the road. You are now done.");

        }


    }

}
```

I'm not understanding why this is not stopping, once numstop is equal to 1 shouldn't the loop terminate?

stack overflow is making me post more details and there really isn't anything to post please do not read this as it just contains a bunch of words if you're still reading please stop reading now

Comment: Please read [ask] and try to make a [mcve]. Your question is missing a clear problem statement. Also, please format your code...

Comment: As per the code the loop will continue to run until numstop does not become 1. your while can be rewritten to while(numstop!=1). Are you sure you are hitting this scenario

Answer (score 1):

The loop will continue to the end of the loop, at which point it will check whether the `while` loop is still valid. Essentially, it will carry out everything inside the `while` loop no matter what, and will not stop to reconsider whether the `while` loop condition is still valid until it reaches the end, and loops back around.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear as to what the aim of your code is, but if you want to break with everything unrolled like that, you will need to check for the case that causes the loop to exit after each number input, then manually break the loop. Though I am confused as to why you wouldn't append each character to a string instead and then loop over until the stop token is encountered then manually break.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this style of coding this, then just add a check before the reading of the next letter. For instance,

```
            letter1=TextIO.getChar();
            System.out.println("Do you awant to stop? Press 1 for Yes, otherwise press a different number.");
            numstop=TextIO.getInt();
            System.out.println(numstop);
            if (numstop==1) break;
            letter2=TextIO.getChar();
             ...
```